# Show that the curvature $K$ of a metric $\rho$ is negative

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry

I am working on the following problem:

> Let $\alpha>0$ and define on $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$ the metric
>   $$\rho(z)=|z|^{\alpha-1}(1+|z|^{2\alpha})^{1/2}$$
>   Show that the curvature of $\rho$ satisfies $K_{\rho}<0$.

---

My attempt:

According to the definition of curvature 
$$K=-\frac{1}{\rho^2}\Delta\log \rho=-\frac{1}{|z|^{2(\alpha-1)}+|z|^{4\alpha-2}}\Delta\log \rho$$
What we need to do is to show
$$\Delta\log \rho>0$$
The Laplace operator is hard to deal with. I know the Laplace operator is that if a $C^2$ function $u(z)$ has a local maximum at a point $p$, then $\Delta u(p)\leq 0$. But I don't know how to prove the positivity.

Comment: It is obvious when $\alpha>1$. So we need to show this for $0<\alpha<1$.

Comment: **HINT**: Use $\bar\partial\partial$ rather than the usual real formula for the Laplacian.

Comment: @TedShifrin Could you explain more or give some reference? I think our complex analysis class does not contain this material.

Comment: Most complex analysis books should introduce $\partial/\partial z$ and $\partial/\partial\bar z$ in terms of $\partial/\partial x$ and $\partial/\partial y$. Then the usual Laplacian is a constant ($4$) times $\partial^2/\partial z\partial\bar z$.